# Sistema de filtro por categoria

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Queria fazer um sistema de busca onde buscaria dados digitados de acordo com a categoria selecionada, porém não sei por onde começo.

Eu gostaria de adicionar a opção de **filtrar** por **categoria** seguida de um `_<input type="text">_` para o usuário selecionar a categoria e escrever o que ele quer buscar :

```
<select name="opcao_filtro">
           <option value="nulo">--</option>                
           <option value="titulo">Título</option>
           <option value="autor">Autor</option>
           <option value="tema">Tema</option>
           <option value="editora">Editora</option>
           <option value="indice">Índice</option>
</select>
```

Logo abaixo teria o input:

```
<input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
<input type="submit" value="Procurar">
```

E depois(opcional para o usuário) buscar por letras(funcionaria junto com o filtro de categorias):

```
<a href="url">A</a>
<a href="url">B</a>
```

**Exemplo**: Usúario escolheu filtrar por título e quando ele clica na letra *" A "* buscasse entre a categoria e exibisse os resultados dos títulos que comesse com a letra selecionada.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia adicionar os filtros na url, ou seja, pode jogar o seu select dentro do form.

Na página que vai receber a requisição poderia fazer algo do tipo:

Vou fazer com PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;','username','password');
$categoria = $_GET['opcao_filtro'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE t.categorias = ?");
$stmt->execute($categoria); //SE FOSSE 2 PARAMETROS, PASSE UM ARRAY
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

É basicamente isso, não sei como está seu back-end, a questão de buscar por letras, você só teria que mudar a query para algo do tipo:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE t.produtos LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$letra", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Caso tenha dúvidas sobre o PDO, utilize o [guia](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) pra referência.

Caso não tenha entendido o like, leia esta [explicação](http://siani.com.br/site/singlepost/index/utilizando-o-operador-like-em-consultas-mysql).

Espero ter conseguido te dar uma luz de como fazer isso. Não consigo explicar um pouco melhor, pois não sei se está utilizando framework ou não, o que está usando pra fazer a ponte entre programação e banco, mas ai está um exemplo genérico.